# Georeference DXF file which doesn't have a SRS assigned

Tags: gdal, geojson, georeferencing, mapbox-gl-js, dxf

I have a DXF file which I converted from DWG (CAD) file. I convert it GeoJSON using ogr2ogr but the output coordinates are out range of WGS 84. I think it's been assigned with the random coordinates.

Now I want it to georeference either by using a script with four known coordinates or on the frontend by converting it to GeoJSON and the drag it to the the exact location on the map, like Mapbox is doing in this link
https://labs.mapbox.com/labs/dxf2geojson/dist/#1.5/30.5/7.7

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that:

- the `DXF` file must have kept the original values of the coordinates
- with "random coordinates" you mean "random coordinate reference system". this is not realistic; at most a "default CRS" (like WGS84) could have been assigned by ogr2ogr
- since the DXF file was generated in CAD, the original CRS is a projected one (like UTM, for example), not a lat/lon CRS like WGS84.

That being said, I think there is no need to reproject the DXF or geojeson file.

Instead, just instruct `ogr2ogr` about the original CRS.

To identify the original CRS, I would recommend observing the coordinates of the original DXF (in CAD, GIS, or even reading it with a text editor) and, also based on the geographical area it shows, “guess” the CRS.

Underlying a satellite map (for example Google Map) is a very useful trick in this case.

Without knowing more, I would bet that the file’s CRS was a UTM/WGS84

Comment: Coordinates are in following form  "717751.281597093795426, 734135.754965581698343"

but my question is if CAD file is being drawn using No SRS and the lengths are in just meter or feet unit then ogr2ogr will convert it into which SRS?

Comment: from https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dxf.html: "DXF files are considered to have no georeferencing information through OGR". so no reprojection occours and the file is translated only from a format point of view. Coordinates in the DXF will be found identical in the output file.

Comment: Those coordinates could be UTM meters if your area of interest is a lot closer to the equator  (734,000 meters north or south) than I am in the Mojave.